# Move rows to be on the same height?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-wrangling

[[image: demographic birth history data] (demographic birth histories)[1]]
The image above shows the first ~20 rows of my df.

The goal is to move the b3_01 - b3_10 rows to be on the same height as rows that have a number in the v011 column. For example, caseid #4 is the mom and case ids #5 and 6 are her kids. I want both of the 1297s to be next to the 973.

I'm stumped!

```
structure(list(caseid = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20), v008 = c(1417, 1417, 1417, 1417, 1417, 1417, 1417, 1417, 1417, 1417, 1417, 1417, 1417, 1417, 1417, 1417, 1417, 1417, 1417, 1417), v011 = c(1081, NA, NA, 973, NA, NA, NA, 709, NA, NA, NA, 1045, NA, NA, NA, 877, NA, NA, NA, 685), b3_01 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1297, NA, NA, NA, 1189, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1405, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1297, NA), b3_02 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1297, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1393, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1225, NA, NA), b3_03 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1189, NA, NA, NA), b3_04 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), b3_05 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), b3_06 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), b3_07 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), b3_08 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), b3_09 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), b3_10 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

So far I tried to bump up the b3_01-b3_10 values, by they are not always the same distance apart (e.g. b3_01 is not always 1 below v011).

```
## Not the solution, but nice try  
      hello4 <- hello4 %>% 
        mutate_at(c("b3_01"), funs(lead), n = 1)

      hello4 <- hello4 %>% 
        mutate_at(c("b3_02"), funs(lead), n = 2)

      hello4 <- hello4 %>% 
        mutate_at(c("b3_03"), funs(lead), n = 3)

      etc.
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Pictures of data are not helpful because we can't copy/paste the data for testing.

Comment: Of course, done.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the [`fill`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/fill.html) function from the **`tidyr`** package. First, we fill in missing values for `v011`, then we fill in the remaining columns after grouping by `v011`. Filling in the missing values for `v011` is necessary, because it is the variable we group by. If you need to retain its missingness, you could create a copy of the column (`v011_copy`).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

d %>%
    fill(v011, .direction = "down") %>%
    group_by(v011) %>%
    fill(-caseid, -v008, -v011, .direction = "up")

#    caseid  v008  v011 b3_01 b3_02 b3_03
#     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#  1      1  1417  1081    NA    NA    NA
#  2      2  1417  1081    NA    NA    NA
#  3      3  1417  1081    NA    NA    NA
#  4      4  1417   973  1297  1297    NA
#  5      5  1417   973  1297  1297    NA
#  6      6  1417   973    NA  1297    NA
#  7      7  1417   973    NA    NA    NA
#  8      8  1417   709  1189    NA    NA
#  9      9  1417   709  1189    NA    NA
# 10     10  1417   709    NA    NA    NA
# 11     11  1417   709    NA    NA    NA
# ...
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `na.locf` from `zoo`

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
nm1 <- setdiff(names(d), c("caseid", "v008", "v011"))
setDT(d)[, v011 := na.locf0(v011)]
d[,  (nm1) :=  lapply(.SD, na.locf0, fromLast = TRUE), 
         v011, .SDcols = nm1]
d[, 1:6]
#    caseid v008 v011 b3_01 b3_02 b3_03
# 1:      1 1417 1081    NA    NA    NA
# 2:      2 1417 1081    NA    NA    NA
# 3:      3 1417 1081    NA    NA    NA
# 4:      4 1417  973  1297  1297    NA
# 5:      5 1417  973  1297  1297    NA
# 6:      6 1417  973    NA  1297    NA
# 7:      7 1417  973    NA    NA    NA
# 8:      8 1417  709  1189    NA    NA
# 9:      9 1417  709  1189    NA    NA
#10:     10 1417  709    NA    NA    NA
#11:     11 1417  709    NA    NA    NA
#12:     12 1417 1045  1405  1393    NA
#13:     13 1417 1045  1405  1393    NA
#14:     14 1417 1045  1405    NA    NA
#15:     15 1417 1045    NA    NA    NA
#16:     16 1417  877  1297  1225  1189
#17:     17 1417  877  1297  1225  1189
#18:     18 1417  877  1297  1225    NA
#19:     19 1417  877  1297    NA    NA
#20:     20 1417  685    NA    NA    NA
```

Comment: This is great! All I have to do then is delete the repeating rows.  BH_clean <- test_df %>% 
          drop_na(v011)